# "It doesn't matter" or "It don't matter"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct: "It doesn't matter" or "It don't matter"?
I think the first one is correct but in the lyrics of Adele's song, "Hello", the second one is written.

Comment: In regual usage, "it *don't* matter" would be considered uneducated at best, although as informal slang may be acceptable depending on the setting. Lyrics can say whatever they want.

Comment: Song lyrics will ignore the rules of standard grammar and should never be used as a guide. The songwriter may pick a non-standard form so that it matches the rhythm of the song better, so that it rhymes better, because it is more evocative of a place or time, because it is in or emulating a dialect, to be provocative or rebellious, and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“It doesn't matter” or “It don't matter”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88292/it-doesnt-matter-or-it-dont-matter) (used up my daily limit for closevotes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Does" is for a singular noun (but only in the third person as pointed out by snailplane), and "do" is for a plural noun.  You could say "they do matter", but "it does matter".  Adding the word "not" does not change the rule:

> It doesn't matter.

Never expect that song lyrics or similar texts (such as stories) will use "standard grammar." Lyrics and other such texts employ the grammar of the person who wrote them ... even if the author uses grammar that differs from standard grammar.

Comment: Good answer, but *does* isn't just singular, it's specifically the *third-person* singular present form.  In the present tense, we use *does* for third-person singular, and *do* for everything else.  This distinction is important because we don't say *\*I does*, even though *I* is singular.

Answer (score 2):

"It doesn't matter!" is correct, but usually the americans could say "It don't matter!" It's a way to say informally.

Comment: We ask for explanations with answers. Simply stating the right answer is not helpful. See [_Submitting Answers that merely answer the question_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/submitting-answers-that-merely-answer-the-question).

Answer (score 0):

In the 16-ish century both of "does not" and "do not" were shortened to "don't". "Doesn't" appeared a lil bit later though... However it is still used in some rural dialects.
It is okay to say "it don't matter" instead of "it doesn't matter" if it is kind of informal speech