# Is the sentence "If he don't come, ring and shout!" correct?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

While reading Tolkien's The Fellowship of The Ring, I noticed one character saying "If he don't come, ring and shout!". Is this sentence really correct, or did the author purposely wrote it wrong? If it is right, what rule explains the use of "don't" instead of "doesn't"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“It doesn't matter” or “It don't matter”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88292/it-doesnt-matter-or-it-dont-matter) (used up my daily limit for closevotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Don't" is sometimes used in place of "doesn't" in some *regional dialects*. The British English accents that use this might be described as "[West Country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_English)" or "rural" dialects. It isn't grammatically correct, but recognisable by native speakers.

[This article](https://teacherluke.co.uk/2016/11/30/404-british-accents-in-the-lord-of-the-rings-part-1/) nicely explains some of the British English dialects used in Lord of The Rings. In particular, this quotation covers your example:

> Frodo – speaks in standard RP
>
> Hobbits – Generally the Hobbits are associated with a kind of rural, local charm. They’re warm characters with a strong sense of local identity. They work on the land. Imagine any part of England about 100 years ago. Farmers, local shopkeepers and things like that. All the hobbits have accents to give this kind of colour to their characters. Frodo speaks with RP because he’s from a slightly higher class than the others. Interestingly, the Hobbits don’t let their class differences come between them, which is another attractive thing about them.
>
> Sam – comes from the South West – a stereotype of the country ‘bumpkin’. it’s a soft and homely accent. Working class because Sam is definitely a working class country boy to Frodo’s upper-class master.